# Where to get really all-in-one .net 3.5 package?

Tags: .net

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=en

there we can see:

> Full Package
>   To download the full package, rather than the bootstrapper, click on the link below:
>   .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 (Full Package)

but this "Full" package still requires 50mb to download over the internet.

Is it possible to get the really-Full package to install on the desktop that haven't internet at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the full package.  After you've downloaded it, you shouldn't need internet access to install it.  What do you mean by "still requires 50mb to download"?  It's going to be large.  If you're trying to install it on a machine that doesn't have internet access, put the full package on a USB thumb drive or burn it to a CD/DVD.

If you want .NET 3.5 *with* SP1, you can download both full packages.  For the .NET 3.5 full package, see the "Full Redistributable Package" section [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325FD-AE52-4E35-B531-508D977D32A6&displaylang=en#Instructions).

Comment: >> That is the full package. After you've downloaded it, you shouldn't need internet access to install it. -- nope. after installer started it requires 50mb to be downloaded. this was checked twice on just installed windows server 2008 r2.

Comment: Interesting, did it say specifically what it was trying to download?

Comment: Try using Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what HTTP requests its making.  That might tell you what additional packages it needs.  According to the comments at http://www.technixupdate.com/net-framework-2-0-3-0-3-5-3-5-sp1-full-setup-standalone-installer-offline-installers/, it sounds like it might be language packs.  You might also want to try the full download at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=D0E5DEA7-AC26-4AD7-B68C-FE5076BBA986&displaylang=en.  I'm not sure if it's different, but it is larger (231 MB).

Comment: it is the same "full package" ;-) not sure it is language packs, OS's i've tried to install was english...